# Undefined Controlled Sequence-\begin{document}

Tags: compiling, compilation-error, undefined, sequence

I know that this question exists in several threads already. But I looked around with no luck. This is the code that I am using.

```
%\title{University of Bristol Thesis Template}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}        % Warns for incorrect (obsolete) LaTeX usage

%
%
% File: memoirthesis.tex
% Author: Victor Brena
% Description: Contains the thesis template using memoir class,
% which is mainly based on book class but permits better control of 
% chapter styles for example. This template is an adaptation and 
% modification of Oscar's.
% 
% Memoir is a flexible class for typesetting poetry, fiction, 
% non-fiction and mathematical works as books, reports, articles or
% manuscripts. CTAN repository is found at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/
%
%
% UoB guidelines for thesis presentation were found at:
% http://www.bris.ac.uk/esu/pg/pgrcop11-12topic.pdf#page=49
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% The dissertation must be printed on A4 white paper. Paper up to A3 may be used
% for maps, plans, diagrams and illustrative material. Pages (apart from the
% preliminary pages) should normally be double-sided.
%
% Memoir class loads useful packages by default (see manual).
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openbib]{memoir} %add 'draft' to turn draft option on (see below)

%memoir option openright to openany 
% Adding metadata:
\usepackage[french,main=english,english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Author's name)
   /Title (PhD Thesis)
   /Keywords (One; Two;Three)
   /CreationDate (D:\pdfdate)
}
\fi
% When draft option is on. 
\ifdraftdoc 
    \usepackage{draftwatermark}             %Sets watermarks up.
    \SetWatermarkScale{0.3}
    \SetWatermarkText{\bf Draft: \today}
\fi
%
% Declare figure/table as a subfloat.
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
% Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing
% Font with math support: New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% Text should be in double or 1.5 line spacing, and font size should be
% chosen to ensure clarity and legibility for the main text and for any
% quotations and footnotes. Margins should allow for eventual hard binding.
%
% Note: This is automatically set by memoir class. Nevertheless \OnehalfSpacing 
% enables double spacing but leaves single spaced for captions for instance. 
\OnehalfSpacing 
%
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
% Chapter style (taken and slightly modified from Lars Madsen Memoir Chapter 
% Styles document

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
        }}%
        \rotatebox{90}{% 
            \resizebox{%
                \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
        \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleifmodif}
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
% page.
\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}
%
% Oscar's command (it works):
% Fills blank pages until next odd-numbered page. Used to emulate single-sided
% frontmatter. This will work for title, abstract and declaration. Though the
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
% contents sections will each start on an odd-numbered page they will
% spill over onto the even-numbered pages if extending beyond one page
% (hopefully, this is ok).
%\usepackage{subfig}
% or load ’graphicx’ and ’blindtext’ manually
% Creates indexes for Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables and Index
\makeindex
% \printglossaries below creates a list of abbreviations. \gls and related
% commands are then used throughout the text, so that latex can automatically
% keep track of which abbreviations have already been defined in the text.
%
% The import command enables each chapter tex file to use relative paths when
% accessing supplementary files. For example, to include
% chapters/brewing/images/figure1.png from chapters/brewing/brewing.tex we can
% use
% \includegraphics{images/figure1}
% instead of
% \includegraphics{chapters/brewing/images/figure1}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}
% Add other packages needed for chapters here. For example:
\usepackage{lipsum}                 %Needed to create dummy text
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   %Calls Amer. Math. Soc. (AMS) fonts
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}            %Writes maths centred down
\usepackage{stmaryrd}                   %New AMS symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %Calls AMS symbols
\usepackage{amsthm}                 %Calls AMS theorem environment
\usepackage{newlfont}                   %Helpful package for fonts and symbols
\usepackage{layouts}                    %Layout diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx}                   %Calls figure environment
\usepackage{longtable,rotating}         %Long tab environments including rotation. 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}         %Needed to encode non-english characters 
                                    %directly for mac
\usepackage{colortbl}                   %Makes coloured tables
\usepackage{wasysym}                    %More math symbols
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                   %Even more math symbols
\usepackage{float}                      %Helps to place figures, tables, etc. 
\usepackage{verbatim}                   %Permits pre-formated text insertion
\usepackage{upgreek }                   %Calls other kind of greek alphabet
\usepackage{latexsym}                   %Extra symbols
\usepackage[square,numbers,
             sort&compress]{natbib}     %Calls bibliography commands 
\usepackage{url}                        %Supports url commands
\usepackage{etex}                       %eTeXÕs extended support for counters
\usepackage{fixltx2e}                   %Eliminates some in felicities of the 
                                    %original LaTeX kernel
%\usepackage[french]{babel}     %For languages characters and hyphenation

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{color}                                  %Creates coloured text and background
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
             allcolors=black]{hyperref}              %Creates hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{memhfixc}                   %Must be used on memoir document 
                                    %class after hyperref
\usepackage{enumerate}                  %For enumeration counter
\usepackage{footnote}                   %For footnotes
\usepackage{microtype}                  %Makes pdf look better.
\usepackage{rotfloat}                   %For rotating and float environments as tables, 
                                        %figures, etc. 
\usepackage{alltt}                      %LaTeX commands are not disabled in 
                                    %verbatim-like environment
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}          %PGF/TikZ is a tandem of languages for producing vector graphics from a 
\usepackage{tikz}                       %geometric/algebraic description.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}               %To use diverse features from tikz  
               

%Reduce widows  (the last line of a paragraph at the start of a page) and orphans 
% (the first line of paragraph at the end of a page)
\pretolerance=150
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}

%
% New command definitions for my thesis
%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\noindent{\small{\bf Keywords:} #1}} %Defines keywords small section
\newcommand{\parcial}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}                             %Defines a partial operator
\newcommand{\vectorr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}                                                        %Defines a bold vector
\newcommand{\vecol}[2]{\left(                                                                         %Defines a column vector
    \begin{array}{c} 
        \displaystyle#1 \\
        \displaystyle#2
    \end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\mados}[4]{\left(                                                                       %Defines a 2x2 matrix
    \begin{array}{cc}
        \displaystyle#1 &\displaystyle #2 \\
        \displaystyle#3 & \displaystyle#4
    \end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\pgftextcircled}[1]{                                                                    %Defines encircled text
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \dimen0\wd0%
    \divide\dimen0 by 2%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]%
        \useasboundingbox (-\the\dimen0,0pt) rectangle (\the\dimen0,1pt);
        \node[circle,draw,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0.1ex] (a) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\range}[1]{\textnormal{range }#1}                                             %Defines range operator
\newcommand{\innerp}[2]{\left\langle#1,#2\right\rangle}                                 %Defines inner product
\newcommand{\prom}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}                                         %Defines average operator
\newcommand{\tra}[1]{\textnormal{tra} \: #1}                                                       %Defines trace operator
\newcommand{\sign}[1]{\textnormal{sign\,}#1}                                                   %Defines sign operator
\newcommand{\sech}[1]{\textnormal{sech} #1}                                                  %Defines sech
\newcommand{\diag}[1]{\textnormal{diag} #1}                                                    %Defines diag operator
\newcommand{\arcsech}[1]{\textnormal{arcsech} #1}                                       %Defines arcsech
\newcommand{\arctanh}[1]{\textnormal{arctanh} #1}                                         %Defines arctanh
%Change tombstone symbol
\newcommand{\blackged}{\hfill$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\whiteged}{\hfill$\square$}
\newcounter{proofcount}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname.]{\par
 \ifnum \theproofcount>0 \pushQED{\whiteged} \else \pushQED{\blackged} \fi%
 \refstepcounter{proofcount}
 \normalfont 
 \trivlist
 \item[\hskip\labelsep
       \itshape
   {\bf\em #1}]\ignorespaces
}{%
 \addtocounter{proofcount}{-1}
 \popQED\endtrivlist
}
%
%
% New definition of square root:
% it renames \sqrt as \oldsqrt
\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
% it defines the new \sqrt in terms of the old one
\def\sqrt{\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
\advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
{\box0\lower0.4pt\box2}}
%
% My caption style
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \captionnamefont{\scshape} 
    \changecaptionwidth
    \captionwidth{0.9\linewidth}
    \captiondelim{.\:} 
    \indentcaption{0.75cm}
    \captionstyle[\centering]{}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \caption{#2}\else \caption[#1]{#2}
}
%
% My subcaption style
\newcommand{\mysubcaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \subcaptionsize{\small}
    \hangsubcaption
    \subcaptionlabelfont{\rmfamily}
    \sidecapstyle{\raggedright}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \subcaption{#2}\else \subcaption[#1]{#2}
}
%
%An initial of the very first character of the content
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,nindent=0em]{
        \color{gray}
            {\textsc{#1}}}{}}
%
% Theorem styles used in my thesis
%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{resu}{Result}[chapter]
%
% Hyphenation for some words
%
\hyphenation{res-pec-tively}
\hyphenation{mono-ti-ca-lly}
\hyphenation{hypo-the-sis}
\hyphenation{para-me-ters}
\hyphenation{sol-va-bi-li-ty}
%

\usepackage[english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\def\nomname{Liste des abr\'eviations}
%\renewcommand{\nomname}{Liste des abr\'eviations}
\begin{document}
% UoB guidlines:
%
% Preliminary pages
% 

% The five preliminary pages must be the Title Page, Abstract, Dedication
% and Acknowledgements, Author's Declaration and Table of Contents.
% These should be single-sided.
% 
% Table of contents, list of tables and illustrative material
% 
% The table of contents must list, with page numbers, all chapters,
 % sections and subsections, the list of references, bibliography, list of
% abbreviations and appendices. The list of tables and illustrations
% should follow the table of contents, listing with page numbers the
% tables, photographs, diagrams, etc., in the order in which they appear

% in the text.
% 
\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{roman}
%
\input{frontmatter/abstract}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\input{frontmatter/dedication}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\input{frontmatter/acknowledgement}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\input{frontmatter/Forward}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\bf Page}\par\nobreak}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\listoftables
\addtocontents{loc}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Table} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{loc}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Figure} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
\clearemptydoublepage

%
%\input{frontmatter/Introduction}
% The bulk of the document is delegated to these chapter files in
% subdirectories.
\mainmatter
%
\addcontentsline{toc}{1}{Introduction}
\import{chapters/chapter00/}{Introduction.tex}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\import{chapters/chapter01/}{chap01.tex}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\import{chapters/chapter02/}{chap02.tex}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\import{chapters/chapter03/}{chap03.tex}
\clearemptydoublepage
%
\import{chapters/chapter04/}{chap04.tex}
\clearemptydoublepage

%
\import{chapters/chapter05/}{chap05.tex}
\clearemptydoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{6}{Conclusion g\'en\'erale}
%\import{chapters/chapter05/}{Conclusion.tex}
%
\addcontentsline{toc}{6}{General Conclusion}
\import{chapters/chapter06/}{Conclusion.tex}

%\clearemptydoublepage
% Apparently the guidelines don't say anything about citations or
% bibliography styles so I guess we can use anything.
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\bibliography{thesisbiblio}


%\clearemptydoublepage
%
% And the appendix goes here
\appendix
\import{chapters/appendices/}{app0A.tex}
\backmatter
% Add index
%\printindex

%   
\end{document}
```

I was not able to fix the error that says:

```
Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

 En savoir plus
<argument> \sf@counterlist 
                           
l.339 \begin{document}
                      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

After some tests this error appears now:

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

 En savoir plus
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 ...erline {1}Evapotranspiration}{7}{chapter.1}
                                                  %
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[9]
Overfull \hbox (1.20142pt too wide) detected at line 73
 \T1/fnc/m/n/10.95 103
 []
```

Comment: Do you really need all that preamble to reproduce the error? I would hazard a guess that some part of it is the cause. Have you tried commenting out bits and see what happens when you compile again?

Comment: yes I did, I look around and saw that some packages can clash so I eliminated those first and then there was the language packages etc... But no luck

Comment: What happens if you comment out `\usepackage{subfig}`?

Comment: @Alenanno same error I am afraid.

Comment: @RimSleimi That error is caused by `subfig`, removing the package also removes the error for me. However your MWE is not very minimal and produces a lot of unrelated errors in my system. Is your TeX distribution up to date? Try updating it again and retry.

Comment: @Alenanno the file compiles for me if I comment out \hyperref! Maybe the two are clashing.

Comment: @Alenanno I am using Overleaf editor

Comment: In a case like this I take the preamble separately from the whole document with a rudimentary \begin{document} \end{document}. Then you comment everything in the preamble. It should compile and then you uncomment sparingly until you end up with the error. You comment out the error and go ahead with the preamble. The offending lines will then end up in MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE short MWE. This you present with the question if there remains any.

Comment: Ok I tried this and now it shows a different error (see edit) I checked that chapter but all the items had \begin {itemize} and \end {itemize}. I am really lost.